# Android M permission revocation - protecting a service with a "dangerous" permission

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, android-service-binding

I have app A which exposes a service through an AIDL and app B which binds to and invokes methods on that service. App A defines a custom permission with "dangerous" protectionLevel which is used to guard the service and is claimed by app B.

Does Android M provide the user the ability to revoke custom dangerous permissions via settings or does this apply to only stock dangerous permissions?

If custom dangerous permissions are revocable, what would happen if the user revoked the custom dangerous permission from App B while App B was bound to App A? Would Android immediately kill the binding resulting in App B receiving an onServiceDisconnected callback, or is the dangerous permission only enforced when the binding initially occurs?

Comment: "what would happen if the user revoked the custom dangerous permission from App B while App B was bound to App A?" -- App B's process should be terminated. I am not aware that binding changes the story; if the user revokes a permission, the affected process is terminated.

Comment: I'd expect App B to be killed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does Android M provide the user the ability to revoke custom dangerous permissions via settings ?

The Answer is Yes.

App A > define custom permission with protection-level "dangerous"
App B > request App A's custom permission with (uses-permission) tag

Installing App B
[image]

Settings > Apps > App B > Permissions
I can revoke this custom permission.
[image]